# Unable to send images to other apps, tried hike, Messenger and Whatsapp

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sharing

I am trying to share images from my app to other app (Hike, Facebook, Messenger etc) but every time I am getting different error. Gone through almost every Q&A but problem not solved yet.

**This is my code**:

```
                       filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                       cacheDir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath()
                       + "/LikeIT/");
                       cacheDir.mkdirs();
                       Intent intent = new Intent();
                       intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                       intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                       intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(cacheDir
                                       .getAbsolutePath())));
                       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

                       activity.startActivity(intent);
```

**I have changed the below line many times, but didn't get the solution:**

```
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(cacheDir
                                       .getAbsolutePath())));
```

**I have changed this with**:

```
  1.  intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(str1));
  2.  intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file1);
```

but didn't get as needed. And also when i am sending image to Whatsapp it is not showing image, and after sending it is showing.

[image]

Comment: what problem you facing?did you try with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code that works fine in my app

```
public void onShareItem(View v) {
        // Get access to bitmap image from view

        // Get access to the URI for the bitmap
        Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(descpic);
        if (bmpUri != null) {
            // Construct a ShareIntent with link to image
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, desc.getText().toString());
            shareIntent.setType("image/*");
            // Launch sharing dialog for image
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
        } else {
            // ...sharing failed, handle error
            Log.e("check for intent", "Couldn't get anything");
        }
    }

    // Returns the URI path to the Bitmap displayed in specified ImageView
    public Uri getLocalBitmapUri(ImageView imageView) {
        imageView.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bm = imageView.getDrawingCache();

        OutputStream fOut = null;
        Uri outputFileUri=null;
        try {
            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "folder_name" + File.separator);
            root.mkdirs();
            File imageFile = new File(root, "myPicName.jpg");
            outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error occured. Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
            return outputFileUri;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: what is "descpic" and "desc" here? got red after i implemented this, in my code

Comment: descpic is imageview and desc  textview,change it with your text

Answer (score -1):

**TL;DR :::  You need to enable read/write permissions for WhatsAPP (or any other APP) to use the images.  Create a temporary file --- OR --- make your APP save files to external storage.**

- This tutorial helped me out: [Saving the bitmap to the external storage](https://web.archive.org/web/20200629021941/http://www.e-nature.ch:80/tech/saving-loading-bitmaps-to-the-android-device-storage-internal-external/)
- This android developer link, explained to me why I had to go the  `getExternalStorageDirectory()` route :      [Develop > Training > Getting > Started > Saving Data](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#InternalVsExternalStorage)

This is exactly what happened to me and my app.  Took me a day of fiddling around, and I've finally resolved it.

No matter what,  this line of code did not work (or anything relating to modifying the `Uri` object ) :   `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);`

Nor the following from `FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("desiredFilename.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`
then changing  `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` to  `Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE` ... which was deprecated after API-14

It's not anything wrong with this part:

```
 filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                       cacheDir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath()
                       + "/LikeIT/");
                       cacheDir.mkdirs();
                       Intent intent = new Intent();
                       intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                       intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                       intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(cacheDir
                                       .getAbsolutePath())));
```

That part is working just fine,  since it starts the WhatsApp process --- and waits for you to add a caption.  By adding  `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text_string);`   it'll take whatever string values  found in  `text_string` and adds it as the pictures caption.  Unfortunately, `intent.putExtra()` is received/understood by WhatsAPP with just one picture with one caption ... I'm not sure how to make it multiple pictures with multiple captions...

Another tip:  In case the error output says `File(s) Directory doesn't exist`, it's likely due to the fact that the line `mkdirs()` did not work.  The tutorial uses two chosen directories `APP_PATH_SD_CARD` and `APP_THUMBNAIL_PATH_SD_CARD` ---  and asks  `mkdirs()` to create both of them at the same time... which for some reason,  `mkdirs()` does not like to do.
So I asked `mkdirs()` to create them one at a time:

```
   File dir = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + APP_PATH_SD_CARD );
   if (!dir.exists()) { dir.mkdirs();}

  File dirHoldingImages = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + APP_PATH_SD_CARD + APP_THUMBNAIL_PATH_SD_CARD);
    if (!dirHoldingImages.exists()) { dirHoldingImages.mkdirs(); }

// carry-on with the rest of the saveFileToExternalStorage code
```

Hope those links helps others that stumble across the same issues. :)